# Dynamic Oracle Table Function for use in Tableau

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, tableau-api, table-functions

We have a large amount of data in an Oracle 11g server. Most of the engineers use Tableau for visualizing data, but there is currently not a great solution for visualizing straight from the Oracle server because of the structure of the database. Unfortunately, this cannot be changed, as it's very deeply integrated with the rest of our systems. There is a "dictionary" table, let's call it `tab_keys`:

```
name  |   key
---------------
AB-7  |  19756
BG-0  |  76519
FY-10 |  79513
JB-2  |  18765
...
...
```

And there are also the tables actually containing the data. Each entry in `tab_keys` has a corresponding data table named by prefixing the key with an identifier, in this case, we'll use "dat_". So AB-7 will store all its data in a table called `dat_19756`. These keys are not known to the user, and are only used for tracking "behind the scenes". The user only knows the AB-7 moniker.

Tableau allows communication with Oracle servers using standard SQL select statements, but because the user doesn't know the key value, they cannot write a SQL statement to query the data.

Tableau recently added the ability for users to query Oracle Table Functions, so I started going down the road of writing a table function to query for the key, and return a table of the results for Tableau to use. The problem is that each dat_ table is basically unique with a different numbers of columns, labels, number of records, and datatypes from the next dat_ table.

What is the right way to handle this problem? Can I:

1) Write a function (which tableau can call inline in regular SQL) to return a bonified table name which is dynamically generated? I tried this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEST_FUNC 
(
  V_NAME IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN user_tables.table_name%type AS 
V_KEY VARCHAR(100);
V_TABLE user_tables.table_name%type;
BEGIN
  select KEY into V_KEY from my_schema.tab_keys where NAME = V_NAME;
  V_TABLE := dbms_assert.sql_object_name('my_schema.dat_' || V_KEY);
  RETURN V_TABLE;
END TEST_FUNC;
```

and then `SELECT * from TABLE(TEST_FUNC('AB-7'));` but I get:

```
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
*Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
           parse time or that is not of a nested table type
*Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type
```

I couldn't figure out a good way to CAST the table as the table type I needed. Could this be done in the function before returning?

2) Write a table function? Tableau can supposedly query these like tables, but then I run into the problem of dynamically generating types (which I understand isn't easy) but with the added complication of this needing to be used by multiple users simultaneously, so each user would need a data type generated for them each time they connect to a table (if I'm understanding this correctly).

I have to think I'm missing something simple. How do I cast the return of this query as this other table's datatype?

Comment: `user_tables.table_name%type` defines a variable with the same type as that column name, in this case VARCHAR2(30). It's not a record matching the projection of the table; which would be `user_tables%rowtype` but is a scalar (not a multi-row set) and anyway is a PL/SQL construct not understood by SQL.

Comment: How about dynamic SQL? I do not envy you here...

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to have a single generic function return a dynamically configurable nested table. With other products you could use a Ref Cursor (which maps to ODBC or JDBC `ResultSet` object) but my understanding is Tableau does not support that option.

One thing you can do is generate views from your data dictionary. You can use this query to produce a one-off script.

```
select 'create or replace view "' || name || '" as select * from dat_' || key || ';'
from tab_keys;
```

The double-quotes are necessary because `AB-7` is not a valid object name in Oracle, due to the dash.

This would allow your users to query their data like this:

```
select * from "AB-7";
```

Note they would have to use the double-quotes too.

Obviously, any time you inserted a row in `tab_keys` you'd need to create the required view. That could be done through a trigger.

Comment: This could work. What about when data is added to any of the dat_ tables? Would the script need to be run again, or are the views updated?

Comment: Views are basically just a stored query: a view returns whatever data is in the underlying table(s) when you select from it.

Comment: Ah, I just tested this and discovered Tableau doesn't allow you to parameterize table names in custom sql queries. So close.

Comment: This is not asking for parameterized table name.  This is saying that you access views in tableau.  Views will look like simple tables

Comment: Right, I guess I should have said "Tableau doesn't let you parameterize anything in the FROM clause", so I can't have the table or view name be a parameter the users can enter. It must be explicit in the custom SQL query.

Comment: So this comes down to how you use Tableau. I have no experience of Tableau (until now it's always been BO) but surely at some point you must be writing actually SQL which selects from tables? I don't understand why selecting from views is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can build dynamic SQL in SQL using the open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4):

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select 'select *  from dat_'||key
        from tab_keys
        where name = 'AB-7'
    ]'
));

A
-
1
```

The program combines Oracle Data Cartridge Interface with `ANYDATASET` to create a function that can return dynamic types.

There might be a way to further simplify the interface but I haven't figured it out yet.  These Oracle  Data Cartridge Interface functions are very picky and are not easy to repackage.

Here's the sample schema I used:

```
create table tab_keys(name varchar2(100), key varchar2(100));
insert into tab_keys
select 'AB-7' , '19756' from dual union all
select 'BG-0' , '76519' from dual union all
select 'FY-10', '79513' from dual union all
select 'JB-2' , '18765' from dual;

create table dat_19756 as select 1 a from dual;
create table dat_76519 as select 2 b from dual;
create table dat_79513 as select 3 c from dual;
create table dat_18765 as select 4 d from dual;
```

Comment: This looks promising. How would Tableau be able to leverage this? I'm assuming you install this on whatever system is producing the queries?

Comment: @HudsonMC Yes, the program must be installed on the Oracle database.  The steps are listed on the repository page, it's mostly download the program and run `@install` in SQL*Plus.

Comment: Lot of products like SAP/BO, Tableau, Documentum,... don't support function's syntax in the "FROM" clause, only in the "SELECT" part... as @H

Comment: @p3consulting I'm not familiar with those products, but in my experience there's often a way around those limitations. For example, there may be a way to hand-write queries instead of using a query builder, or you can hide the complicated query inside a view (although that might ruin the query if you need to pass in parameters).

Comment: @JonHeller: yes hiding the "from function(with parameters)" into a view (meaning a VIEW per parameters set...) is often the only solution, but with drawbacks specific to each product and also drawbacks in the way of working: it requires collaboration between teams, in general (in medium to large organizations) the "reporting" team has no write access to the database.